# Is it possible to continue from a checkpoint after exiting level?

Tags: james-bond-007-blood-stone

I'm currently in the middle of a mission. I've reached a few checkpoints within the mission so far. I wonder if it would be worth finishing the level or if I can just start from the last checkpoint when coming back to this game. I want to avoid redoing the whole level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just quit the game and tested it out. I could continue from the checkpoint and did not need to redo the whole level.